# How to call a method of a class from an rxjs observable subscription

Tags: javascript, rxjs

Could I please ask:

This code works fine:

```
class MyClass
{
  constructor()
  {
    this.m_observable = Rx.Observable.of(1, 2);
    
      this.m_observable.subscribe(
                                 function (x) {alert(x);}
                                 );
  }
  
  DoIt(x)
  {
    alert(5 * x);
  }
}
```

When I create a new instance of the class I see "1" then "2".

I would like to call the DoIt method of the class when the subscription fires, this code does **not** work, I see no alerts:

```
class rxjsShapeShifter
{
  constructor()
  {
    this.m_observable = Rx.Observable.of(1, 2);
    
      this.m_observable.subscribe(
                                 this.DoIt;
                                 );
  }
  
  DoIt(x)
  {
    alert(5 * x);
  }
}
```

How can I call that method from the observable subscription?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: This code seems like it should work. Does your real `DoIt()` method actually look like that or does it try and access `this` inside of it? Do you see any errors in your console?

Comment: Also you have `this.DoIt;` it should be just `this.DoIt`

Comment: That was it, thank you, yes, the semi-colon should not have been there. Thanks very much.

Answer (score 2):

I think you have typo in your `subscribe`. The second code of your should be:

```js
    constructor() {
      this.m_observable = Rx.Observable.of(1, 2);
      this.m_observable.subscribe(this.DoIt);
    }
    
    DoIt(x) {
      alert(5 * x);
    }
```

Comment: Thanks very much, the ; was not required. Thanks.

Comment: @HassanMoin - When a question is typo-based, it is best to use the "close" option under the question and vote to close it as "A community-specific reason" > "Not reproducible or was caused by a typo" rather than adding an answer